# SortedDictionary Keys and Values have ToArray method in some places, but not others

Tags: vb.net, generics, collections

I'm attempting a linear interpolation calculation on a `SortedDictionary` of structures, like this:-

Main Program

```
Imports Measurements.Measurements

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click( sender As System.Object,  e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim mydic As SortedDictionary(Of Distance, Temperature) =
                        New SortedDictionary(Of Distance, Temperature)
    mydic.Add(Distance.FromMetres(20), Temperature.FromCentigrade(30))
    mydic.Add(Distance.FromMetres(0), Temperature.FromCentigrade(10))

    Dim dicinterpolated_temperature As Temperature = DicInterpolate
                                                       (Distance.FromMetres(7),
                                                        mydic)
End Sub

Public Function DicInterpolate (Of YType As {Structure, IMeasurements}, _
                                   XType As {Structure, IMeasurements}) _
                  (ByVal x_value           As XType,
                   ByVal sorted_dictionary As SortedDictionary(Of XType, YType)) _
         As YType
            Return Interpolate (x_value,
                                sorted_dictionary.Keys.ToArray,
                                sorted_dictionary.Values.ToArray)
End Function

End Class
```

Where `Distance` and `Temperature` are structures implementing `IComparable` and `IMeasurements` among other things, and defined in the `Measurements` namespace. This call invokes a function in the `Measurements` project thus...

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Namespace Measurements

    Public Module Interpolation

        Public Function Interpolate (Of YType As {Structure, IMeasurements}, _
                                        XType As {Structure, IMeasurements}) _
                                    (ByVal x3 As XType,
                                     ByVal x_values() As XType, _
                                     ByVal y_values() As YType) _
                                     As YType
            ' calculate the answer and return it.
        End Function

    End Module

End Namespace
```

So far, so good. This is all fine and dandy. But when I attempt to push the DicInterpolate function into the Measurements namespace, where it really belongs, I get compilation errors on this line:-

```
Return Interpolate (x_value,
                    sorted_dictionary.Keys.ToArray,
                    sorted_dictionary.Values.ToArray)
```

The errors reported are:-

```
'ToArray' is not a member of System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary(Of XType, YType).KeyCollection
'ToArray' is not a member of System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary(Of XType, YType).ValueCollection
```

Does anyone know why this might be, and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx) is an extension method of [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which belongs to the `System.Linq` namespace. So you have to add the reference and add `Imports System.Linq` either globally(in project settings) or at the top of the VB-File.